# Installing Android Support Repository offline

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to setup Android Studio + Android SDK on Linux. I was able to setup Android Studio and SDK Tools and other components except "Android Support Repository" (The download kept failing) so I downloaded `android_m2repository_r30.zip` and tried to place its contents(which is a directory `m2repository`) in the **SDK** directory tree but it is not recognized.

I have tried placing in several paths including

`pathtosdk/extras/android/m2repository` , `pathtosdk/extras/android/support/m2repository`

and

`pathtosdk/extras/support/m2repository`

But none of them works. Where should I place the contents of the zip file to have it installed.

Comment: in case someone kept failing install Android Support Repository using SDK Manager or from Android Studio update notice, the cause is permission. I place my Sdk in /home partition, and never had permission issue. Then I came to check the sdkpath/extras/android/m2repository, I realize that root is the owner of m2repository folder. So I simply change its permission as my username. And it's working now. Ps. I launch Android Studio as general user, not root, so that won't install the update on 'root owner' folder.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/135186/242345 The only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 57):

1. Download the latest support repository.
   [Here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip) is the link for version v47
   To get the most recent version check out the update below
2. Extract the downloaded zip file.
3. Copy the folder named `m2repository` from the extracted folder.
4. Navigate to `extras/android` directory in your SDK installation directory. For me it's:
   `C:\Users\$usrname$\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\`
5. Replace the existing `m2repository` folder with the one from the ZIP.
   (I suggest creating a backup first)
6. Restart Android studio.

Hopefully you will have the newer Android support repository.

**Update**

To get the latest version of support repository:

**a.** Go to [this link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml)

**b.** Search for the keyword `m2repository_r`

**c.** Copy the value in `<url>` tag.
It should look like this:

```
 <complete>
    <size>355529608</size>
    <checksum>a0d22beacc106a6977321f2b07d692ce4979e96a</checksum>
    <url>android_m2repository_rXX.zip</url>
 </complete>
```

**d.** Paste it to the end of this URL: `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/`
Your new URL should look like this:
`https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_rXX.zip`
where `XX` is the version number

**e.** Download and continue from step 2

Comment: Waah Vipul... It worked for me like a charm. Upvoted

Answer (score 6):

You can put the downloaded zipped file in the Temp folder under the Android SDK (`C:\Users\$usrname$\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\temp`). Then restart the SDK manager and install it.

Comment: Solution is working OK, except in my case temporary folder is `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk`.

Answer (score 2):

For macOS:

1. Download [android_m2repository_r47.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip)
2. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> from finder and then type

   ```
   ~/Library/
   ```

   And press <kbd>return</kbd>
3. Then go to `android/sdk/extras/android`
4. Then extract and save the files under the `m2repository` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem for the version of Android 2.3.1 and the android_m2repository_r47 package.

1. Download android_m2repository_r47.zip manually.
2. Download xml - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml
3. Copy this 2 files to %\Android Studio\plugins\sdk-updates\offline-repo\
4. Modify addon2-1.xml: delete all "**remotePackage**" tags exclude tag with android_m2repository_r47
5. In Android Studio need add new repository. As URL need to write path to your **modificated** %\Android Studio\plugins\sdk-updates\offline-repo\addon2-1.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste the content of the folder in: 
Program Files\android\android studio\gradle\m2repository

I've tried and it worked well:)

Answer (score 0):

#### If you have another computer(or friend's computer) that working android studio,

just copy the sdk folder

- typically C:\Users\$usrname$\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
- and need to zipping (too many folders and files in it)

---

#### oops, My first computer os is windows 10 64bit and second computer os is windows 7 32bit

#### and sdk trouble occurred

and I found another solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401974/set-up-for-android-studio-gets-stuck?newreg=6723a6530b15490289e0cca070950030)

> After 5?minutes the install seemed to go through (not sure though if it just timed out... but at least starting downloading rest of files) ... now stuck on sdk-tools-darwin-###.zip and went through after few minutes... now stuck again at emulator-darwin-4266726.zip, then build_tools_r27-macosx.zip. then on google_m2repository_gms_v11_3_rc05_wear_2_0_5.zip.... and then platform-27-r01.zip and so on... Will report back if it actually still installed everything and works. – armyofda12mnkeys Nov 3 '17 at 18:11

and I'm happy now