# How to do Android support repository offline update?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to update my Android Support Repository to a version higher than 26.0.0-alpha1.

But I'm using the Android Studio in offline mode.

I can't use Internet for security. So I could find the Support Repository revision 47, but I need higher than 47 (higher 26.0.0-alpha1).

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Having said that: please understand that asking for "offsite" recommendations, such as libraries, download sites, ...etc. is off topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Android Support Repository offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936271/installing-android-support-repository-offline)